# Test that empty flux is returned using StepVerifier

Tags: automated-tests, timeout, spring-webflux, project-reactor, is-empty

I am using StepVerifier to test an INFINITE flux stream. When I expect results, it works as expected. I get the result I am looking for, cancel and verify. When I do NOT expect results, I would like to wait 15 seconds, have the flux cancel/verify as a successful test. I am using

```
StepVerifier
   .create(response.get().timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
   .expectSubscription()
   .verifyComplete();
```

This waits for the default client timeout of 2 minutes before cancelling the flux.

I've also tried

```
StepVerifier
   .create(response.get().timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
   .thenCancel()
   .verify();
```

And several combinations of those methods.

Comment: you can use `thenAwait(Duation duration)` https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Step.html#thenAwait-java.time.Duration- if you just want to wait after the subscription.

Comment: As a side note : There is doc about virtual timing  in step verifier, to be able to simulate long waiting times instantly : https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_manipulating_time

Comment: Because it's an infinite stream, thenAwait() doesn't work. It still waits for the client to timeout. I've looked into StepVerifier.withVirtualTime, but can't seem to come up with a solution that will work for an infinite stream that doesn't return anything. I need to verify that when users query for data they don't have access to, that data will not return.